# Apache download files with specific extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, download

I have download directory on apache webserver. Files in this directory have specific extensions. For example *.yyy and *.zzz. But all these files are renamed .zip or .tar.gz

I've tested in different brawsers and havn't got any problems.

But some users tell that they get source of packages, not download.

I've created.htaccess

```
AddType application/zip .zzz
AddType application/x-gzip .yyy
```

But when I try to download aaa.yyy in MS Internet Explorer it try to save not aaa.**yyy** but aaa.**gz**

How to force browsers download files and not to change extensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(zzz|yyy)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Force type tell browsers that you dont know file type. So they are not going to do any thing stupid. Second line will tell them to download this file.

Comment: All files in this derectory should be downloadable. Could i use something like <FilesMatch "\.(.)*$">

Comment: Removing filesmatch should do what you need.

Comment: Answer can be improved by also sending the file name, like `Content-Disposition => attachment; filename=CrashPlan_2011_1.16_arm-x09.qpkg` as can be seen at http://serverfault.com/questions/101948/how-to-send-content-disposition-headers-in-apache-for-files