# CSv file is opening in same page

Tags: apache

> We upgraded Apache after that CSV file is opening in same page. we want to download the csv file. Which propertied need to be changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing a download using <filesMatch> in htaccess at WWW root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess-at-www-root)

Comment: You need to send appropriate http headers marking the payload as either an "attachment" or something the browser should not interpret inline.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643232/apache-download-files-with-specific-extension